# RabbitMQ on Kubernates Unacked messages in queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We are having issue on rabbitmq that happens when we deploy the application on production, we are not able to reproduce the issue on our development environment.
We have a microservices architecture with multiple spring boot applications deployed on kubernates with autoscaler depends on the usage and we notice that after sometimes some Unacked messages are created in queue, the number of Unacked messages will increase with the time and after sometimes rabbitmq seems to stop working.
Is there something we can check in order to identify the problem?